# create child class from parent class, same arguments

Tags: python, class, instantiation

I have a parent class `Parent` and a child class `Child` that forwards all initialization arguments to `Parent`. (It only add a few methods.)

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, alpha, beta, zeta, omicron):
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.c = alpha + beta + zeta + omicron


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def show(self):
        print(self.alpha, self.c)


p = Parent(23.7, 0.0, 1.0, -4.1)

# create Child from p?
# c = ... ?
```

Given a parent class instance, how can I best create a child class instance from it?
I though could add something like

```py
@classmethod
def from_parent(cls, parent):
    return cls(
        parent.alpha,
        # parent.beta,
        # parent.zeta,
        # parent.omicron
    )
```

but `Parent` doesn't have all arguments that are necessary to create another instance from it.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general way to do what you want. Any implementation will be specific to your classes.

However, in the case where the `Child` class doesn't do anything at all in its `__init__` (which is equivalent to not having an `__init__` at all), you can actually change the class of the `Parent` object you already have:

```
p.__class__ = Child
```

Note that this is modifying the object in place, it's not making a new copy of the object that's a `Child`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it seems `Parent.__init__` does too much. The additional three arguments are independent of an instance of `Parent`; they are just one way to define the `c` attribute.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.c = c

    @classmethod
    def from_parameters(cls, alpha, beta, zeta, omicron):
        return cls(alpha, alpha + beta + zeta + omicron)


class Child(Parent):

    # Seemingly belongs in Parent, not here.
    def show(self):
        print(self.alpha, self.c)

    @classmethod
    def from_parent(cls, p):
        return cls(p.alpha, p.c)


p = Parent.from_parameters(23.7, 0.0, 1.0, -4.1)
c = Child.from_parent(p)
```